# VB.net Framework 3.5 OnClose() or OnDestroy()

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I apologize, as I believe the question is pretty basic. I'm looking to do some clean up on a form when it closes. Other languages have `OnClose()` or `OnDestroy()` methods. What is the equivalent for VB.net that uses .NET 3.5 framework?

Comment: It has been a while, hence why this is a comment and not an answer, but I believe you have the .Dispose() method at your disposal.

Comment: If WinForms, just override the `OnFormClosing` method.

Comment: Use OnFormClosed instead.  Then it is really dead.

Comment: DHT is correct. However Dispose() on controls are not overridable. Controls however to supply you with a Dispose event. 

FormClosed event simply means the form is closed, it has not been unloaded from memory yet.

A closed form is not disposed of if it is simply Closed or hidden, because form.Show() can still be used on that instance, it is still in memory. 

To destroy the form ( or any object Inheriting from Control ) - the Dispose() method should be used, ( and thus also - absolute cleanup should be done in the Dispose event ).
 - Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**System.Windows.Forms.Form** implements the IDisposable interface. Do like any object that Implements IDisposable, cleanup code is best placed within the Dispose event or routine.

See the following example, showing the following event handlers:

- event Form.Disposed
- event Form.FormClosed
- event Form.FormClosing

  Public Class Form1

  ```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      REM     we are loaded... probably  =)

  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Disposed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed

      REM     Put cleanup code here...

      REM     when we are done here the form will be completly disposed of

  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

      REM     Here the form is CLOSED but not disposed YET!

  End Sub


  Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

      REM     Here the form is CLosing, but has not closed yet, and the closing behavior itself can actually be aborted:

      REM     To cancel the closing of a form you can:

      ' e.Cancel = True 

  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Me.Dispose()
  End Sub
  ```

  End Class

As as result you can also dispose via the Using Statement:
The **Using** keyword is available for all objects that implement the IDisposable interface.

```
 using frm as new form() ' A new form is created here
     frm.ShowDialog()  ' form is displayed as a Modal form (  dialog ) 
 end using             ' form is Disposed() of here.
```